# Why a person get birth as a woman?

Tags: women, rebirth

Why a person take birth as a woman ? What is the reason behind it ? [What sin a person commit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pVfzWguUl_k) in their previous lives to take birth as a woman ?
Can someone cite the scriptures regarding it ?

Comment: > What sin did a person commit in their previous lives to take birth as a woman?

Apparently, committing *sin* will NOT lead to your birth as a *woman*, but it'll ultimately lead you to a *birth*. Only the sinless are liberated.

Answer (score 0):

as per bhagvad gita (chapter 8 shloka 6), what thought that comes in the mind of a human being at the time of death he or she gets that type of body in next birth. so humans who dies thinking about women at the time of death, they takes birth as a woman in next birth.

Answer (score -1):

Birth of woman is highly sacred. She is born to protect generations of noble man. It holds good for all females of all religion not just Hinduism.
Unfortunately woman is dejected because woman lacks physical force / strength but has physical bearing ability than man.

In kali yuga noble men population gets reduced such that it does not suit women's sacred callibre making them feel unworthy to sustain the generation of the degraded.